# Why is my CHECKOUT stream event failing in Sitecore CDP/Sitecore Personalize?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

When trying to create an order in `Sitecore CDP`/`Sitecore Personalize`, I am sending in an **ADD**, **CONFIRM** and **CHECKOUT** event but my checkout event is continuously failing. Why are some reasons that a **CHECKOUT** event might fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some common issues that cause a **CHECKOUT** event to fail, resulting in no order being created in `Sitecore CDP`/`Sitecore Personalize`.

- `item_id` is in the **CONFIRM** event, but there is no corresponding **ADD** event for this item id. For example, if in **CONFIRM** event, products
  with item id `ITEM_1`, `ITEM_2` and `ITEM_3` are included. Then
  there should be a corresponding **ADD** event for each with `item_id`
  **ITEM_1**, **ITEM_2** and **ITEM_3**. If an **ADD** event is missing for one
  of these item_ids in the **CONFIRM** event, the **CHECKOUT** event will fail.
- Missing/Invalid **ADD** event (check all values supplied are valid
  against the API documentation, such as using strings instead of
  numbers). See our documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-an-add-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html
- Missing/invalid **CONFIRM** event. See our documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-a-confirm-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html
- Missing/invalid **CHECKOUT** event . See our documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-a-checkout-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html

For more information see our knowledge hub: https://sitecore.cdpknowledgehub.com/docs/web-tagging-testing-and-troubleshooting#orders-not-created

Answer (score 1):

It can be also wrong format of data in the CONFIRM event.
Make sure that you always send list of products as array - even when you want to confirm only one product.

If you send something like that:

```
var viewEvent = {
      "browser_id" : _boxever.getID(),
      "channel" : "WEB",
      "type" : "CONFIRM",
      "language" : "EN",
      "currency" : "USD",
      "page" : window.location.href,
      "pos" : "Sygnity",
      "product" : 
        {"item_id" : "LenovoX1"}
      ,
      "_bx_extended_message" : "1"
    };
    _boxever.eventCreate(viewEvent, function(data){},"json");
```

Sitecore CDP will accept it and even (according to the debug mode) process it:

```
{
  "ref": "488ee8a3-f57c-4870-976d-cce0529971ad",
  "clientKey": "psfu6uh05hsr9c34rptlr06dn864cqrx",
  "createdAt": "2022-02-15T16:00:30.893Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2022-02-15T16:00:30.897Z",
  "type": "CONFIRM",
  "status": "PROCESSED",
  "channel": "WEB",
  "pointOfSale": "Sygnity",
  "browserRef": "31f55dae-04b1-4708-83e7-3f13f8817a7d",
  "sessionRef": "6c31e4ba-0263-4cae-b08d-e99bd0aae30a",
  "arbitraryData": {
    "product": {
      "item_id": "LenovoX1"
    },
    "_bx_version": "1.2",
    "language": "EN",
    "page": "https://polarized-disco-click.glitch.me/",
    "currency": "USD",
    "_bx_extended_message": "1"
  },
  "flowExecution": {}
},
```

But CHECKOUT event will fail.

If you send the same CONFIRM event with products in array structure:

```
var viewEvent = {
      "browser_id" : _boxever.getID(),
      "channel" : "WEB",
      "type" : "CONFIRM",
      "language" : "EN",
      "currency" : "USD",
      "page" : window.location.href,
      "pos" : "Sygnity",
      "product" : [
        {"item_id" : "LenovoX1"}
      ],
      "_bx_extended_message" : "1"
    };
    _boxever.eventCreate(viewEvent, function(data){},"json");
```

Result in the debug mode will be exactly the same (with different structure of the product data):

```
{
  "ref": "803ee756-84a5-45cb-906c-516f8641aee2",
  "clientKey": "psfu6uh05hsr9c34rptlr06dn864cqrx",
  "createdAt": "2022-02-15T16:05:30.865Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2022-02-15T16:05:30.875Z",
  "type": "CONFIRM",
  "status": "PROCESSED",
  "channel": "WEB",
  "pointOfSale": "Sygnity",
  "browserRef": "31f55dae-04b1-4708-83e7-3f13f8817a7d",
  "sessionRef": "ab65ddc4-e1bf-4b29-9336-501b5bd13751",
  "arbitraryData": {
    "product": [
      {
        "item_id": "LenovoX1"
      }
    ],
    "_bx_version": "1.2",
    "language": "EN",
    "page": "https://polarized-disco-click.glitch.me/",
    "currency": "USD",
    "_bx_extended_message": "1"
  },
  "flowExecution": {}
}
```

The difference will be visible in the result of CHECKOUT event which this time will be successful.

You can be also confused with the UI of CDP becasue in two scenarios purchase will be visible as "complete" (even when it failed it is still green).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same parameters which are required even with the matching `item_id` but still checkout event was failing. The root cause for that was having the product type as "**FLIGHT**" like below.

```
           "product": {
                "type": "FLIGHT",
                "item_id": "FLIGHT_1",
                "name": "DUB-LHR Economy Flight",
                "currency": "USD",
                "price": 200,
                "product_id": "DUB-LHR|Economy|EconomyPlus",
                "quantity": 1
            }
```

When I replace type as "**FLIGHT**" with anything else like "**FOOD**", it started working.

```
            "product": {
                "type": "FOOD",
                "item_id": "FLIGHT_1",
                "name": "DUB-LHR Economy Flight",
                "currency": "USD",
                "price": 200,
                "product_id": "DUB-LHR|Economy|EconomyPlus",
                "quantity": 1
            }
```