# In Sitecore CDP, why does my converted session or abandoned session have no amount in the timeline?

Tags: cdp

When my guest has a converted session or an abandoned session, I expect to see the amount in the converted or abandoned amount in timeline, however mine is always showing as zero. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a converted session or an abandoned session in the timeline for your guest profile, but the amount shown is zero (as shown in the image in the question) then there is likely to be an issue with one of the following:

1. Currency is not valid in the ADD event
2. Price is being sent as a string, not a number in the ADD event

Developer documentation for ADD events: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-an-add-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html

Answer (score 2):

The amount can be also equal to 0 because CHECKOUT event was not processed successfully.

Check details of the purchase in the details of session by clicking debug icon.

[image]

Then show all data as a JSON

[image]

Then find CHECKOUT event in the JSON. It will look like this one:

```
{
  "ref": "2dbdd87e-2117-4358-936a-c1f0aeea3e51",
  "clientKey": "psfu6uh05hsr9c34rptlr06dn864cqrx",
  "createdAt": "2022-02-15T16:00:31.457Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2022-02-15T16:00:31.538Z",
  "type": "CHECKOUT",
  "status": "FAILED",
  "channel": "WEB",
  "pointOfSale": "Sygnity",
  "browserRef": "31f55dae-04b1-4708-83e7-3f13f8817a7d",
  "sessionRef": "6c31e4ba-0263-4cae-b08d-e99bd0aae30a",
  "arbitraryData": {
    "page": "https://polarized-disco-click.glitch.me/",
    "status": "PURCHASED",
    "_bx_extended_message": "1",
    "reference_id": "ORDER1644940830308",
    "_bx_version": "1.2",
    "language": "EN",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "flowExecution": {}
}
```

As you may notice the status is equal to "FAILED". There can be multiple reasons behind it. Some of them are explained here: [Why is my CHECKOUT stream event failing in Sitecore CDP/Sitecore Personalize?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30928/why-is-my-checkout-stream-event-failing-in-sitecore-cdp-sitecore-personalize)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar situation when I couldn't find any value attached to the session even if the order is successfully captured.
You have to send the order reference in each add event as reference_id.

[Send ADD event](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-an-add-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html)

[image]